# get list of items from sku magento 2 programatically

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, magento2.2, magento2.4

I want to fetch items from skus. Can anyone suggest me how to do.

The code I am following -
The sku i am getting in the variable $productSkus.

```
private function fetchProducts(array $orderItems): array
{
    $productIds = [];

    foreach ($orderItems as $orderItem) {
        $productIds[] = $orderItem->getProductId();
        $productSkus[] = $orderItem->getSku();
    }
```

}
Now, i want to get all items from the skus array